# Barra Lateral responsiva de acordo com informações

Tags: css, html5, laravel-blade

Eu não estou conseguindo deixar o meu menu responsivo, digo, no caso se eu colocar várias informações no centro do container ele quebra, gostaria que esse menu se estendesse ou algo similar a isso... Como faria?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que não ficasse esse espaço em branco, existe alguma forma? Tipo assim (imagem a seguir), porém com conteúdo

[image: insira o código aqui]

Meus códigos HTML e CSS são:

```css
      nav {
    
        background-color: #2f3e53;
    
    }
    
    .nav-wrapper a.button {
    
        margin: 0% 0% 0% 3%;
        display:none;
    
    }
    
    .barra-lateral {
    
        background-color: #697586;
        color:white;
        width:30%;
        font-size:1.30em;
        
    
    }
    
     li {
        
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 2% 5%;
    
    }
    .container.corpo {
    
        margin-left:40%;
        margin-top:-28%;
        padding-top:2%;
        width:60%;
    
    }
    footer{
        margin-top: 26%;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
    
            <!--<a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src=" {{ asset('assets.Painel.img.logo.png') }}"></a>-->
    
    
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    
                <li><a href="">Perfil  </a></li>
    
    
            </ul>
            <a class="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
    
        </div>
    
    </nav>
    
    <div class="barra-lateral">
    
            <li><i class="fas fa-user"></i>    Perfil  
                <ul>
                    <li>Editar Perfil</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>    Home         </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>    Cursos  
                <ul>
                    <li>Adicionar Curso</li>
                    <li>Editar Curso</li>
                    <li>Excluir Curso </li>
                    <li>Consultar lista de Cursos</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>    Categoria de Cursos     
                <ul>
                    <li>Adicionar Categoria de Curso</li>
                    <li>Editar Categoria de Curso</li>
                    <li>Excluir Categoria de Curso </li>
                    <li>Consultar Categoria de lista de Cursos</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-gifts"></i>    Combos      </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>    Notícias    </li>
            <li><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>    Categoria de Notícias   </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i>    Clientes    </li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-smile"></i>    Parceiros   </li>
            
    
    </div>
<footer class="page-footer">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col l6 s12">
            <h5 class="white-text">Aos usuários</h5>
            <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Caso encontre algum bug no sistema, por favor informar imediatamente</p>
          </div>



        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="footer-copyright">

        <div class="container">

        © 2019 Instituto Técnico Profissionalizante


        </div>

      </div>
      
    </footer>
```

A parte de `container` não é minha, estou utilizando o *framework* *materialize* para me ajudar com algumas coisas, também estou utilizando para parte de front o sistema de blade do Laravel

Se não fui claro o bastante, vou acrescentar mais informações.

Comment: Cara edita sua pergunta e coloca tb o HTML, sem ele fica complicado te responder...

Comment: Ok, vou editar as informações.

Comment: Cara mas no seu HTML nem tem o footer, ele está bem diferente do que representa a imagem... O ideal é que coloque um código que de para simular melhor o problema que vc tem ai, mas só com esse código não fica igual a imagem

Comment: @hugocsl agora está correto, adicionei os scripts do materialize e a parte do footer do meu rodapé que faltava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara uma opção é envolver a barra lateral e a `div` que vai receber o conteúdo em uma `flex-container`, assim vc coloca de uma vez um ao lado do outro e a sua barra lateral sempre vai acompanhar o tamanho da `div` de conteúdo ao lado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
html,
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav {

 background-color: #2f3e53;

}

.nav-wrapper a.button {

 margin: 0% 0% 0% 3%;
 display: none;

}

.barra-lateral {

 background-color: #697586;
 color: white;
 width: 30%;
 font-size: 1.30em;


}

li {

 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 2% 5%;

}

.container.corpo {

 margin-left: 40%;
 margin-top: -28%;
 padding-top: 2%;
 width: 60%;

}

footer {
 /* margin-top: 26%; */
}

.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
}

.cont {
 width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<nav>

 <div class="nav-wrapper">

  <!--<a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src=" {{ asset('assets.Painel.img.logo.png') }}"></a>-->


  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">

   <li><a href="">Perfil </a></li>


  </ul>
  <a class="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>

 </div>

</nav>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="barra-lateral">

  <li><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Perfil
   <ul>
    <li>Editar Perfil</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i> Cursos
   <ul>
    <li>Adicionar Curso</li>
    <li>Editar Curso</li>
    <li>Excluir Curso </li>
    <li>Consultar lista de Cursos</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i> Categoria de Cursos
   <ul>
    <li>Adicionar Categoria de Curso</li>
    <li>Editar Categoria de Curso</li>
    <li>Excluir Categoria de Curso </li>
    <li>Consultar Categoria de lista de Cursos</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-gifts"></i> Combos </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> Notícias </li>
  <li><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> Categoria de Notícias </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Clientes </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-smile"></i> Parceiros </li>


 </div>
 <div class="cont">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore quas nostrum est excepturi vitae
  recusandae minima ad unde architecto repellendus, doloribus nam dolore, enim ratione tempore, aliquam at
  itaque a accusantium aliquid incidunt. Dolore inventore accusamus eaque, placeat quidem reiciendis, numquam
  illum voluptatum autem dicta rerum! Eaque tempore fugit magnam id atque aut quasi optio similique veniam
  nulla quis beatae odio culpa nam, dicta voluptate architecto vero libero saepe repellat eveniet minus?
  Laboriosam, ipsum alias officia ab iusto reprehenderit iure maiores suscipit eius pariatur asperiores
  consectetur atque soluta id. Placeat sunt id voluptatibus unde praesentium possimus laboriosam in adipisci
  impedit dicta deserunt doloremque nostrum nemo at dolorem beatae fuga, quo tenetur cumque, saepe quis?
  Expedita molestiae, impedit quia itaque dolore in similique laudantium fugit placeat libero optio? Ad sequi
  impedit aspernatur, sed esse nesciunt recusandae aliquam quibusdam blanditiis ut neque consectetur
  dignissimos assumenda odit minima natus aliquid non. Nostrum explicabo, minima similique optio incidunt
  atque possimus id animi assumenda esse ut eveniet est repellendus eum laboriosam totam nemo qui dolor iste
  cupiditate itaque ex ipsum. Repellat, officia enim veniam quos architecto corporis sapiente inventore
  molestias odit. Aut ex optio dignissimos aliquid fugiat, tenetur iusto, qui deserunt numquam amet, sunt
  sapiente laboriosam alias modi ut eaque dolorum maiores doloremque perferendis laudantium ad sit beatae?
  Quasi explicabo quia porro adipisci, consequuntur quibusdam autem. Unde illum voluptate aperiam voluptatem,
  aliquam possimus, obcaecati iusto ullam eos, distinctio rem esse quis temporibus. Possimus, facilis atque
  blanditiis nesciunt laudantium aliquam rem, iste obcaecati perferendis culpa repellat ipsum necessitatibus,
  delectus itaque magni corporis accusantium ab. Consequatur laudantium doloribus 
 </div>
</div>
<footer class="page-footer">

 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">

   <div class="col l6 s12">
    <h5 class="white-text">Aos usuários</h5>
    <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Caso encontre algum bug no sistema, por favor informar
     imediatamente</p>
   </div>



  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="footer-copyright">

  <div class="container">

   © 2019 Instituto Técnico Profissionalizante


  </div>

 </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Hugo, então o container.corpo não usa mais no css? Apenas o cont?

Comment: @RodrigoPires que `container.corpo` não vi ele no seu HTML, não mexi nessa classe pq não tinha elemento com essa classe no HTML, pra fazer na minha resposta eu criei um elemento com a classe .cont ee ficou como vc pode ver na imagem ou no código.... Foi o que eu entendi que vc precisava, com a barra lateral e o .cont são filho de um container felx que chamei de .wrapper eles já ficam ajustados um ao lado do outro, não precisa da classe .container.corpo  ou desses margins que vc usou